# Asp.net Global Date Formats

Tags: sql, asp.net, globalization

I have an asp.net site which displays various data from a SQL backend to users which are in different time zones, i.e. PST, GMT, etc.

How can I easily display the dates on the page but in the time zone that the users are in and not the raw SQL date format?

I know it has to do with globalization settings but I have never used that before.

Comment: what is "raw SQL date format"?

Comment: it is English UK dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: this has little to do with formatting, but a lot to do with converting DateTime **values** between timezones. What is stored in the database, UTC values I hope?

Answer (score 0):

Use two resource (.resx) files with a 'Format_DateTime' key.  Have a value 'dd-mm-yyy HH:mm tt' for the default and a 'mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt' for en-US.

In your page, call MyDate.ToString(Resources.Format_DateTime) .

Comment: Will I need to set this up for every country? I will have users from multiple countries accessing the site not just two and I will not know in advance what countries/regions they are.

Comment: This will not translate the timezone

Comment: Almost every country in the world uses 'dd-mm-yyy HH:mm tt'.  The US is stubborn and does its own thing.  For a full list of date formats, check online on sites like http://en.wikepedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country.

Comment: Don't try to change the time server side based on the Client time settings.  Instead, use a proven date picker control like the one provided by Kendo UI.  It will display the time in the end users time zone while maintaining the UTC time in code.